# NodeJS, callback hell, triggering class event from inside callback

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, asynccallback

I'm trying to write a server, in nodejs, that can be called like so:

```
server.getData()
    .on('complete', function(){
        console.log('on complete triggered');
    });
```

I'm trying to `emit` the event from inside the callback for the response.end, inside the callback for the http.get. like so:

```
Server = function(){
    events.EventEmitter.call(this);

    this.getData = function(fn){

        var _cb;
        fn ? _cb=fn: _cb=this.parseData;
        https.get('https://api.example.com', _cb);
        return this;
    }

    this.parseData = function(resp, fn){
        var _data = '';
        var self = this;
        resp.setEncoding('utf8');
        resp.on( 'data', function(chunk){
            _data += chunk;
        });
        resp.on( 'end', function(){
            var j = JSON.parse(_data);
            self.emit('complete');
            console.log(j);
            if(fn)
                fn(j);
        });
    }
}
util.inherits(Server, events.EventEmitter);
server = new Server();
```

I'm lost as what to do. What is getting me is that I can access the `_data` var in `server.parseData` in `resp.end` but I can't do the same for the server object.

Comment: Why cant you start the class function with a `var Server = this;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line in `parseData` isn't doing what you expect:

```
var self = this;
```

because, at that point, `this` is the global object.  The problem occurs in `getData` when you set:

```
_cb=this.parseData
```

Since you call `_cb()` instead of `this.parseData()`, `this` is not set correctly inside `parseData`.  This is a common problem in JavaScript.  You can either set `self` in the `Server` function, which would give all methods declared inside there access to it, or you can bind it:

```
_cb=this.parseData.bind(this)
```

which will cause `this` to be the right thing when `_cb` is called.